# Flash все moveclip на сцене

Tags: flash

Как можно посмотреть все Moveclip программно находящиеся на текущий сцене. Например я создал Moveclip из библиотеки я их накидал N количество как теперь мне в коде обратиться к ним

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Примерно так, только учтите что на контейнере могут быть и другие мувиклипы, надо как то еще их идентифицировать или складировать отдельно.

```
var parent:DisplayObjectContainer = new DisplayObjectContainer(); 
// Тут нужна ссылка на ваш собственный контейнер где сидят мувиклипы

for (var i:uint=0; i < parent.numChildren; i++) 
{ 
     var o:Object = parent.getChildAt(i);

     if (o is MovieClip)
     {
         var mc:MovieClip = o as MovieClip // Cсылка на мувик.
     }
}
```